# How to remove default iCarousel item centered position?

Tags: icarousel

Anyone can help me out, how to remove default iCarousel item centered position with example?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and do it with following hack ;)

**Problem:** 
I need to have view that display only 3 items that are always left aligned.

**Resolution:**
What I have done is to always make at least 3 items. If I have 0, 1 or 2 items I'm always creating 3, but those that do not need to be shown I'm creating as empty UIView. I always have 2 placeholders, but in some cases one or both  are empty.

e.g.
If we have 2 items to display, I'm actually creating three, but third one is empty UIView. I'm creating two placeholders and one Item.

- First item is first *placeholder* at index 0
- Second item is *Item*
- Third item is second *placeholder* but with empty UIView

If we have 1 items to display, again I'm creating three, but second and third one are empty UIView. Same as in previous example, I'm creating two placeholders and one Item.

- First item is first *placeholder* at index 0
- Second item is *Item* but with empty UIView
- Third item is second *placeholder* but with empty UIView

Because of this logic I'm always cleaning view when reusing ([v removeFromSuperview]), to be sure it is clean and if new one needs to be displayed I'm adding it ([view addSubview...). Same logic for *Item* and *Placeholder*

If you need to have more than 3 displayed items you can use same logic, but change value 3 to something else. If I'm wrong update me ;)

Here is a part of mine code that works for me ;)

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return [[self getRecordings] count] > 3? [[self getRecordings] count] - 2: 1;
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
    }
    else
    {
        // If reusing remove content from holder view for fake items
        for (UIView *v in view.subviews)
        {
            [v removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    if ([[self getRecordings] count] >= 2)
    {
        [view addSubview:[(RecordingItemViewController*)[_recordingItemViewControllers objectAtIndex:index + 1] view]];
    }

    return view;
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfPlaceholdersInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return 2;
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel placeholderViewAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
    }
    else
    {
    // If reusing remove content from holder view for fake items
        for (UIView *v in view.subviews)
        {
            [v removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    if (([[self getRecordings] count] > 0 && [[self getRecordings] count] < 3 && index == 0) || [[self getRecordings]count] >= 3)
    {
        [view addSubview:[(RecordingItemViewController*)(index == 0? [_recordingItemViewControllers objectAtIndex:0]: [_recordingItemViewControllers lastObject]) view]];
    }

    return view;
}
```